# What could cause a discrepancy between local/development and production routing in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Everything in my local environment works fine, but in production on heroku, ajax links which render content at vanity urls ex. `/t/tags` instead of `/atags/1` render an error concerning a lack of id:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"atags", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
```

This makes even less sense, because if I navigate into production to '/t/tags' for example, the page loads fine. So ajax at the route is broken while the same route via a regular rendered view is functional.

What could be causing this error and discrepancy between development and production environments?

I checked routes on heroku and locally and they are identical.

The js that is rendering the view is: `$("#tag_posts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @atag) %>");` So I wonder if it has something to do with @atags path being interpreted differently in production for some reason or what?

The links that are broken are being constructed by:

```
link_to(piece.downcase, atag_path(Atag.find_by(tag:piece[1..-1].downcase)), 
:class => 'post_hashtag', :remote => true, :onclick => "location.href='#top'")
```

And these links constructed by that same code work fine in production minus the `remote:true` and `:onclick => "location.href='#top'"` at rendering regular pages.

```
    link_to(piece.downcase, atag_path(Atag.find_by(tag:piece[1..-1].downcase)),
              :class => 'post_hashtag')
```

And just to note again, both of these types of links work fine in development, just only the latter in production. Any insight into this oddity would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT: I think I've almost narrowed it down. In the atags controller in show I defined:

```
@atag = Atag.find_by_tag(params[:id])
```

Where/how would I make an equivalent definition for other views? That might solve the problem in production. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within the methods at hand `piece[1..-1]` is the tag and the base of the route is `/t/` so changing `atag_path(Atag.find_by(tag:piece[1..-1].downcase))` to `"/t/" + piece[1..-1]` solved the issue, as it directly passes the route as a string. Further, it's much faster than having to go back to the database to find the route.

I'm uncertain/curious why it was fine locally but not in production, though.

Comment: Still having other discrepancies come up only in production. Very bad.